# Sync Google Cloud Message in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I m using Google cloud message to send push message to device, but it have a large delay to send (if i manually click in sync google account, the message come on time). 
I want when i open my app (onResume activity) do "force sync" of google account.

i m trying this way:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_FORCE, true);
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts) {
    SyncAdapterType[] types = ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes();
    for (SyncAdapterType type : types) {
        if (account.type.equals(type.accountType)) {
            boolean isSyncable = ContentResolver.getIsSyncable(account, type.authority) > 0;
            if (isSyncable) {
                ContentResolver.requestSync(account, type.authority, extras);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it ill try sync all account in all ways, AND it dont work my message don't come like when i click in the menu  button of sync.

how i can force (in the better way) my app to check if it have some message in google .cloud?

Comment: May be this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the way you are supposed to use Google Cloud Messaging (or any mobile push notification service). The point in using GCM is to receive messages when the app is not running, in order to alert the user about an event he/she may find interesting, and (hopefully) cause them to launch your app.

When your app is already launched, there is no point in trying to find out if there's any pending GCM message that was sent by your server and weren't delivered yet. Instead, you can simply call your server and get all the data you need to show to the user of the app (including whatever data was in the GCM message that hasn't arrived yet).

Comment: hmmm, good point, i need to think about, but i believe this is the answer of my question.